# Splash Screen(Wait Form) on behind the Mdi Parent Panel

Tags: c#, panel, splash-screen, mdi, mdiparent

I m working on a mdi form application and my mdi parent is a panel on main form.I wanna use a splash screen while my data's loading in child form.

But when i click to action button which is in child form splash screen is activate on behind the main form's panel.(mdi parent)

I tried to brigtofront or something else but i couldn't do it.

main form's code for Show child form:

```
 Tarafekleuc frm1 = new Tarafekleuc();
        frm1.TopLevel = false;
        frm1.Parent = panel1;
        frm1.Show();
```

child form's code for Show splash screen:

```
        loading f2 = new loading();
        f2.Show();
```

Comment: `f2.TopLevel = false;` and `f2.Parent = panel1;` ?

Comment: Try `f2.BringToFront();`

Comment: Check if u make Topmost=true for the main form ,    
Try to use myForm.BringToFront();                    [ f2.BringToFront(); ]

Comment: @RovannLinhalis I did it but not working

Comment: @CodingYoshi Also i tried before